# cv2.getperspectivetransform() assertion failed error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to use cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(), but I keep getting a (-215:Assertion failed) error.

I am using cv2 version "4.8.0.76", numpy version "1.25.2", and python version "3.10.1"

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

srcpoints = np.array([[0,0],[100,0],[200,0],[0,100],[100,100],[200,100],[0,200],[100,200],[200,200]],np.float32)
targetpoints = np.array([[60, 60], [960, 60], [1860, 60], [60, 540], [960, 540], [1860, 540], [60, 1020], [960, 1020], [1860, 1020]],np.float32)

matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(srcpoints, targetpoints)
```

Error in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ishan\PycharmProjects\eye_test\test_matrix.py", line 7, in <module>
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(srcpoints, targetpoints)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:3528: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'cv::getPerspectiveTransform'
```

My real use case has source coordinates that have more decimal places, but even if i simplify the coordinates, the error still happens.

I made sure both the source and target points are in float32, but I cant get it to run the function.

Comment: You need to pass the coordinates of a quadrangle's vertices in both planes. That means you only need to pass 4 points.

Comment: Oh I didnt realize that getperspectivetransform only works for 4 points. Thanks!

Comment: Always read the documentation.  https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae.  If you want to use more than 4 point pairs, the use https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780

Comment: You can use findHomography if you have more than 4 pairs